# How do you add new child entities to a parent in EF4?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4, poco

I am working with VS2010, .NET 4.0, Entity Framework 4, and POCO entities. I am trying to add and remove child entities from a parent. I have a many-to-many relationship between [User] and [Companies]. So I have the following entity:

```
// Objects created by POCO template generator
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

At this point in the code, the User exists but has ZERO companies. What I am trying to do is add a new child Company to the User. This code DOES save the Company but it is also creating a duplicate User parent.

```
public UserRepository
{
    internal ObjectContextEntities _dbContext = new ObjectContextEntities();
    public User Save(User pocoObject)
    {
        // Load the existing User which has no companies
        var loadedEntity = _dbContext.Users.Where(m => m.Id == pocoObject.Id).FirstOrDefault();

        // Add the new company from a POCO object
        loadedEntity.Companies.Add(pocoObject.Companies.Last());

        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

How should I be adding child entities? (Without creating a duplicate relationship?) ... Also is there a simple way to update those children when performing "ApplyCurrentValues()" on the parent User?

Comment: It should work. Did you omit something in your code snippets? `IEnumerable<T>` does not have an `Add` method and your `Save` method would not compile because of this and because you don't return a `User`. I guess, this is not your "real" code, is it?

Comment: Sorry, the POCO generator creates `ICollections`, which I fixed in my snippet. Btw, the line `pocoObject.Companies.Last()` is a POCO object, and not a tracked entity.

Comment: OK, I see. Just to make sure I understand: You **want** to **insert** a new company to the database (`pocoObject.Companies.Last()` is a new company, not yet existing in the DB, right?) and create a relationship between the existing user and this new company, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I want to **INSERT** the new Company into the database, but have it belong to the **EXISTING** User.

Comment: Can you make a little test: Create another context `_dbContext2` in your `Save` method and replace the two `_dbContext` in your code by `_dbContext2`. Execute in debugger and watch the database tables directly after `_dbContext2.SaveChanges()`. If this should work (no user duplication) then you know at least that something else happens with your `_dbContext` instance which causes the duplication.

Comment: I think Slauma is on the right track.  You're doing something to that _dbContext prior to this call to make it think it needs to insert that other user.  You'll need to post a more complete code sample—show everything your doing with this repository object prior t the Save call.

Comment: When I add Customer and Company entities to my model and add Code generation Item POCO Entities Generator it creates different entities. Company has UserId and User reference. Also properties are virtual. And it works.

Comment: As you've been told, there is something else going on with this example.  You need to edit your question to provide a more complete code example, from beginning to end, starting with the moment you create your repository.  Until you do that, nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a more simplified approach and I figured it out:

```
    var newCompany = pocoObject.Companies.Last();
    newCompany.Users = null;
    loadedUser.Companies.Add(newCompany);
```

It turns out because there was a reference to the parent INSIDE the child, it was propagating up and causing a new parent to be created. So from a POCO standpoint, I had to remove the parent and keep it a very simple object. (Or I could have just removed the Child's Parent reference in the edmx). But even this makes my life easier:

```
    loadedUser.Companies.Add(new Company() { Name = "New Company" });
```

Answer (score 1):

This code does work and does not create duplicate users.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        Companies = new List<Company>();
    }
}

public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class POCOEntitiesContext : ObjectContext
{
    private ObjectSet<User> users;
    public ObjectSet<User> Users
    {
        get { return users; }
    }

    private ObjectSet<Company> companies;
    public ObjectSet<Company> Companies
    {
        get { return companies; }
    }

    public POCOEntitiesContext() : base("name=POCOEntities", "POCOEntitiesContainer")
    {
        users = CreateObjectSet<User>();
        companies = CreateObjectSet<Company>();
    }
}

using (var ctx = new POCOEntitiesContext())
{
    var loadedUser = ctx.Users.Where(u => u.Username == "Peri").First();
    loadedUser.Companies.Add(new Company() { Name = "New Company" });
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: You know, I tried this more simplified approach and I figured it out. It turns out because there was a reference to the parent INSIDE the child, it was propagating up and causing a new parent to be created. Thank you so much!!